# Mobile app with Bootstrap 3, jQuery and phonegap, is it possible?

Tags: jquery, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible and doable to develop a mobile application using phonegap as a wrapper, Bootstrap for the UI and jQuery for the functionality?

I could not find any projects on the internet trying this combination.

Bootstrap 3 comes with the mobile-first technology. jQuery can provide all the functionality and Phonegap wrappes it all into an app.

My goal is to create a mobile application.

Any experience or other ideas?

Comment: Yes. You should check out the example on Coenraet's blog: http://coenraets.org/blog/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's possible. Bootstrap is also great. But I think Bootstrap does't focus on mobile app but responsive web app.

Now there are many frameworks focused on rich Mobile UI.

[Framework7](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/)

[Onsen UI](http://onsenui.io/)

[ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)

[crosswalk-project.org](https://crosswalk-project.org/)

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is designed keeping Mobile as a primary. The documentation says it is mobile first. Any one using bootstrap for cordova?

Comment: try ionic, its very promising.. bootstrap is lil heavy for a mobile app i guess..

Comment: I'm currently working on using bootstrap in Cordova, but have run into issues with things just not working there (but work in Bootstrap outside of Cordova, or even in an Electron app, just fine).

Comment: Crosswalk is no longer supported: it's not needed anymore. And that is a good thing, keeps your apps a lot smaller. And http://onsenui.io/ is down.

Answer (score 15):

Yes this is perfectly possible!
In this case Bootstrap would do the front-end stuff, while jQuery does the back-end.

However, to get a framework which is well integrated and **fully designed to build mobile applications**, I would recommend you take a look at the **[ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/)**!

ionic does the front-end and while it is based on AngularJS, Angular can undertake the back-end and totally make your life easier.

Answer (score 8):

Can attest this is possible. Source: [I built one](http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching). Bootstrap renders much more cleanly on IOS than it does on Android, but it saves a heck of a lot of time to build once in Javascript/Jquery and then use phonegap/cordova to compile for Android and IOS. Lots of [great help here at the DevGirl site too](http://www.devgirl.org).

Answer (score 2):

Framework 7 has bad support for firefox browser. I had suffered a lot for that. You check out by doing this:
1.go to framework 7 official page
2.find their docs page and go to the sub header component.
3. in your firefox desktop browser you will notice the header text is not positioned in center. But in chrome you will not face this problem.

this is just a quick example of what i suffered of. I faced more problem with fw7. such as media list was not shoing its text properly on firefox.